# Missing plugins when exporting Eclipse e4 RCP Application containing Birt (Eclipse 2019-3)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, birt

Currently I am in the process of moving one of our RCP applications from an older version of Eclipse to the current version 2019-03.
Our application is feature based an makes use of the Birt report generator. 
When trying to lauch the application via its product-file lots of unresolved plugin requirements appear, as the combination of RCP and Birt now seems to depend on different versions of org.apache.batik.* (1.7.0 and 1.8.0).
I can get the app running by manually enabling the different versions via Run -> Run Configurations -> Plugins. But of course this does not help when trying to export the RCP through the Eclipse product export wizard. The exported app is missing various plugins.
So I tried to manually edit the manifest.mf of the plugin that is dependent on birt:

```
Require-Bundle: 
 org.apache.batik.css;bundle-version="1.7.0",
 org.apache.batik.css;bundle-version="1.8.0",
 ...
```

But this does not seem to have any effect on the plugins beeing exported.

The tip to switch back to a plugin-based project (How best to maintain an Eclipse RCP plugin target? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440458/how-best-to-maintain-an-eclipse-rcp-plugin-target) ) does not seem to work either.
So does anybody know how to get Eclipse to export all required versions of the org.apache.batik plugins?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Tom